# Interval of existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the interval of existence of the following I.V.P

$$y'(t) = \frac{3t^2+4t+2}{2(y(t)-1)}, \quad y(0)=-1.$$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ I proceeded to solve the IVP using the separation of variables

$$2\int (y -1)dy = \int (3t^2+4t+2) dt$$

$$y^2-2y=t^3+2t^2+2t+k,\quad \text{where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ }$$

Now using the I.C we have

$$1+2\cdot -1= 0+0+0+k \implies k = -1$$

The particular solution is therefore

$$y^2-2y=t^3+2t^2+2t-1$$

Solving for $y(t)$ using the quadratic formula we require that

$$2^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot t^3+2t^2+2t-1 \geq 0$$

$$\implies t^3+2t^2+2t-1 \leq 1$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be

> $$ y(t) = 1-\sqrt{t^3+2t^2+2t+4} = 1-\sqrt{(t+2)(t^2+2)} $$

which gives the interval

> $$ t+2 \geq 0 \implies t\geq -2. $$

**Added:** Here are the possible solutions of the ode

> $$ y \left( t \right) =1-\sqrt {{t}^{3}+2\,{t}^{2}+2
> \,t+C+1},\,y \left( t \right) =1+\sqrt {{t}^{3}+2\,{t}^{2}+2\,t
> +C+1}  .$$

Use the initial condition to find $C$ and you will get the answer.

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: @user119264: Where is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @user119264: I have not heard from you!

Comment: Where did the constant term 4 come from under the radical?